# Which recorder do I use for Selenium 2

Tags: testing, selenium

We have a web application that we want to start running regression tests on, and have pretty much decided that we will be using Selenium 2. Not all of the testers are programmer savvy. Is Selenium IDE usable for this? Which other recorder alternatives are best for Selenium 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Not all of the testers are programmer savvy.

Teach them. Or, if some are bright enough and others not, separate them out into automated testing and support (mostly replicating problems that others have found).

This might sound like an onerous task, but it's really not that hard. They don't need to know about hard-core programming to write tests, simply teach them some Java (or whatever the tests are to be written in) and the [PageObject pattern](http://www.theautomatedtester.co.uk/tutorials/selenium/page-object-pattern.htm). That's it. If they can't handle the PageObjects themselves then get the programmers to write those while the testers write the tests on top of them.

I strongly recommend against using recorders. Unless you have no javascript whatsoever, you are going to run into problems that need tweaking and the testers will eventually either need to learn simple programming or rely on programmers' help forever.

Better to teach them early and have a good solid test framework for them to work within.

Answer (score 1):

No, IDE is to help in creating tests not to create tests. You will need to code the tests if you want them to be usable and stable.
As already suggested make the testers learn the tool. No need to learn hard core programmeing, basic Java would suffice.